Error in get_records() function from the getSpatialData library
I am encountering an issue with the get_records() function from the getSpatialData package in R. The error message states: Argument 'products' must be a character containing at least one element.
It seems that the function requires the products argument to specify which data product (e.g., Sentinel-2, etc.) to query. However, I am unsure which product names are valid or how to structure this argument correctly for my area of interest (AOI) and time range.
Any guidance on setting up the products argument or troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated.
# devtools::install_github("16EAGLE/getSpatialData")
library(getSpatialData)
library(sf)

dat <- st_as_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(c(-58.5, -34.9),
                                             c(-58.3, -34.9),
                                             c(-58.3, -34.6),
                                             c(-58.5, -34.6),
                                             c(-58.5, -34.9))))),
                 crs = 4326)
print(dat)

login_CopHub(username = "xxxxx", password = "xxxxx")
out <- get_records(collection = "Sentinel-2",
                   aoi = dat,
                   time_range = c("2023-04-15", "2023-09-15"),
                   max_cloud_cov = 20)

Error: Argument 'products' must be a character containing at least one element.


In your included code you have collection instead of products, a typo? Perhaps start with examples from documentation - https://jakob.schwalb-willmann.de/getSpatialData/index.html#get-started

Thanks for the comment. I have tried it. For example, when I use products = c("Sentinel-2"), the error message says: Argument 'aoi' needs to be a 'SpatialPolygons', 'sfc_POLYGON', or 'matrix' object. This is also unclear to me because the aoi object is already a spatial polygon.

Your dat object is simple feature collection (sf) and not a SpatialPolygons or sfc_POLYGON object. Remove the st_as_sf() wrapper, recreate dat, and change collection to products and try again. For me though, this returned another error that was raised on GitHub nearly a year ago. Therefore it looks like getSpatialData  currently does not work for your use case. Someone on that GitHub ticket suggested openeo as an alternative.

I suspect the issue was caused by changes to the Copernicus Open Access Hub architecture, which occurred October 2023 (so the timing lines up with the aforementioned GitHub ticket).
